# Need help in RegEx to grab anything after a mandatory value

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I have  a text in which I need to grab data and split it up.  I need to find "Review frequency" within a large group of text, then once that is found, take everything after it and stop at the ')'.
Example text is:

```
No. of components Variable
Review frequency Quarterly (Mar., Jun., Sep., Dec.)
Quick facts
To learn more about the
```

What I need is 'Quarterly' and 'Mar., Jun., Sep., Dec.'

My current regex is:

```
((?=.*?\bReview frequency\b)(\b(Q|q)uarterly|(A|a)nnually|(S|s)emi-(A|a)nnually))
```

But this is not working.  Essentially the 'Review frequency' needs to be the qualifier before we start picking up the other information, as there may be other dates/periods within the file.  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [`(?m)^Review frequency\s*(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/p6mT0O/1) is enough? Or [`^Review frequency[ \t]+(\w+)[ \t]+(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/p6mT0O/2)?

Comment: Do you want -- re.search( r'.*Review frequency (.*)', line ).group(1)

Comment: Try (Review frequency)(.+)  Note that if what you want after 'Review frequency' is on a new line, this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not matching the rest of the data on the line.

I suggest using:

```
(?m)^Review frequency[ \t]+(\w+)[ \t]+(.+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p6mT0O/2)

If the first capturing group can only contain 3 words as indicated in your pattern, use

```
(?m)^Review frequency[ \t]+([Qq]uarterly|(?:[Ss]emi-)?[Aa]nnually)[ \t]+(.*)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p6mT0O/3)

[Use these patterns with `re.findall`](http://ideone.com/cOsZEI):

```
import re
regex = r"(?m)^Review frequency[ \t]+([Qq]uarterly|(?:[Ss]emi-)?[Aa]nnually)[ \t]+(.*)"
test = "No. of components Variable\nReview frequency Quarterly (Mar., Jun., Sep., Dec.\nQuick facts\nTo learn more about the"
print(re.findall(regex, test))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this second one works!  How about if I need to incorporate re.MULTILINE into this? or printing the capture groups separate?

Comment: Once you assign the `re.findall` result to a variable, you may print the results as you want.